# GWT Autobeans, parsing root-level as Map or List

Tags: json, gwt, autobean

Autobeans are pretty powerful.  Yet, for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to handle root-level JSON maps or lists.

Most of the documentation suggests that you have a defined top level object that can contain a variety of sub-objects (including lists and maps), yet there is no documentation on autobeaning a Map or List.

```
public interface Types {
    List<FieldType> getTypes();
}

public interface TypesAutoBeanFactory extends AutoBeanFactory {
    AutoBean<Types> jsonItems();
}
```

Above is the referenced way to accomplish Lists, where incoming data will look like:

```
{"types":[{...},{...}]}
```

Yet, I find this ugly and the REST service should correctly return:

```
[{...},{...}]
```

but I cannot find a simple way to handle this with the Autobean framework.  Same goes for root-level maps.

Why does this not work and is there an alternative:

```
public interface TypesAutoBeanFactory extends AutoBeanFactory {
    AutoBean<List<FieldType>> jsonItems();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AutoBean works by scanning your class for `get` and `set` methods (maybe `is` methods too).  `List` doesn't have those methods.

You could write a patch to hook the inner `List` parsing methods directly to the outer `decode` methods of `AutoBeanCodex` - most of the code you need is in there.  Maybe instead of `decode(Class type, Splittable input)` you could just add `decodeList(Splittable input)`.  The result will probably be an actual List instead of an AutoBean.

Comment: I get what you're saying, although neither of those are fairly clean solutions.  The second solution is probably the better of the two.  And instead I could probably decode on each object within the splittable list and ultimately just return the list.  I also require maps, but that might be even trickier...  Still up for more ideas, but thanks for a better direction.

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way I can see isn't fully autobean solution.

It's obvious, that if string starts with `[{`, than it's array, so we can use

```
Object[] array = jsonString.replaceAll("[\[\]]","").split(",");
```

and then just work with elements of array with autobean.

Answer (score 0):

I use the method you describe to decode JSON payloads containing a list under a single key.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13651699/565863) also explains another method you could take to combine the approach you mentioned with unkeyed JSON list payloads.